# Euler Project #1 in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

**Problem**

Find the sum of all numbers below 1000 that can be divisible by 3 or 5

**One solution I created:**

```
x <- c(1:999)
values <- x[x %% 3 == 0 | x %% 5 == 0]
sum(values
```

**Second solution I can't get to work and need help with. I've pasted it below.** 
I'm trying to use a loop (here, I use while() and after this I'll try for()). I am still struggling with keeping references to indexes (locations in a vector) separate from values/observations within vectors. Loops seem to make it more challenging for me to distinguish the two.

**Why does this not produce the answer to Euler #1?**

```
x <- 0
i <- 1
while (i < 100) {
  if (i %% 3 == 0 | i %% 5 == 0) {
    x[i] <- c(x, i)
  }  
  i <- i + 1
}
sum(x)
```

And in words, line by line this is what I understand is happening:

1. x gets value 0
2. i gets value 1
3. while object i's value (not the index #) is < 1000
4. if is divisible by 3 or 5
5. add that number i to the vector x
6. add 1 to i in order (in order to keep the loop going to defined limit of 1e3
7. sum all items in vector x

I am guessing x[i] <- c(x, i) is not the right way to add an element to vector x. How do I fix this and what else is not accurate?

Comment: A more general approach to solving the problem of keeping indexes and values separate is more descriptive names. Although `i` is standard as an index, you're also sort of using it as a number. In this example, you could call `i` `numbers_to_test` and `x` `successes`, and you wouldn't have to work so hard to remember what's what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your loop runs until `i < 100`, not `i < 1000`.

Second, replace `x[i] <- c(x, i)` with `x <- c(x, i)` to add an element to the vector.

Comment: Yep, thanks for catching that (100 vs 1000). Okay, so the use of [] is not necessary to indicate I want to add an item to a vector, correct? Typically I think of x <- as an overwriting function...I'm replacing whatever x currently has with a new value.

Comment: @jmo Your understanding is correct. Each time, you replace `x` with a new (longer) vector.

Comment: Ah, it just clicked. THANK YOU! I've been sitting in front of all kinds of practice problems for some time (I won't confess how long :) trying to really "get it." I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shortcut that performs this sum, which is probably more in the spirit of the problem:

```
3*(333*334/2) + 5*(199*200/2) - 15*(66*67/2)
## [1] 233168
```

Here's why this works:

In the set of integers `[1,999]` there are:

333 values that are divisible by 3.  Their sum is `3*sum(1:333)` or `3*(333*334/2)`.

199 values that are divisible by 5.  Their sum is `5*sum(1:199)` or `5*(199*200/2)`.

Adding these up gives a number that is too high by their intersection, which are the values that are divisible by 15.  There are 66 such values, and their sum is `15*(1:66)` or `15*(66*67/2)`

As a function of N, this can be written:

```
f <- function(N) {
  threes <- floor(N/3)
  fives  <- floor(N/5)
  fifteens <- floor(N/15)

  3*(threes*(threes+1)/2) +  5*(fives*(fives+1)/2) - 15*(fifteens*(fifteens+1)/2)
}
```

Giving:

```
f(999)
## [1] 233168
f(99)
## [1] 2318
```

Comment: This is neat.  I am not certain, but I think the function could even be generalized for any two divisors, i.e., instead of 3, 5 and 15 use a, b and c.

Comment: @MarkMiller Unless you can prove otherwise, I don't think your condition is enough and thus I'm rolling back your edit.  Certainly for `a` and `b` prime it is valid.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I tested the edit for approximately 15 combinations of a and b when n = 20 and it always gave the correct answer.  I will place the edit in my own post.

Comment: @mark Try 10 and 14 with a limit of 1000.  I think you'll see that it is a counterexample.  And I do disagree with you taking my content for your own answer, as this is quite different from what Sven did.  However, you can do what you want with your own answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I do not think I have ever heard of anyone objecting to someone else generalizing open-source code.  Nevertheless, if you feel doing so is an infringement on your content I will not bother.  I do not have time to test the code right now to identify what limitations exist outside of prime numbers, but might do so later.

Comment: @mark Do you realize that there is a limit on the number of edits a post can have before it is converted to CW?  You entered three edits on my post with unproved and invalid code, so perhaps you can see that I might be a bit miffed.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Earlier this morning I think I came up with the required modifications to further generalize your function to handle the counter-example you provided.  I thought the number of edits required to become a community wiki was something like 20.  I suspect the generalized code is valid now.  Sorry I did not provide fully valid code the first time.  I am glad the initial limitation I described was able to help others.

Answer (score 1):

And another way:

```
x <- 1:999
sum(which(x%%5==0 | x%%3==0))
# [1] 233168
```

Answer (score 1):

A very *efficient* approach is the following:

```
div_sum <- function(x, n) {
  # calculates the double of the sum of all integers from 1 to n 
  # that are divisible by x
  max_num <- n %/% x
  (x * (max_num + 1) * max_num)      
}

n <- 999
a <- 3
b <- 5

(div_sum(a, n) + div_sum(b, n) - div_sum(a * b, n)) / 2
```

---

In contrast, a very *short* code is the following:

```
x=1:999
sum(x[!x%%3|!x%%5])
```

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Yes, It is similar to your answer. I just copied it from the solution I discovered when I played around with the Euler problem. I did not want to upset you but share my answer. Of course, I will delete my answer if you prefer. Just let me know.

Comment: No worries.  Note that this solution requires that `a` and `b` be relatively prime.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of this. So, it is not a *general* solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that I think gives the same answer (using 99 instead of 999 as the upper bound):

```
iters <- 100
x <- rep(0, iters-1)
i <- 1

while (i < iters) {
  if (i %% 3 == 0 | i %% 5 == 0) {
    x[i] <- i
  }  
  i <- i + 1
}
sum(x)

# [1] 2318
```

Here is the `for-loop` mentioned in the original post:

```
iters <- 99
x <- rep(0, iters)
i <- 1

for (i in 1:iters) {
  if (i %% 3 == 0 | i %% 5 == 0) {
    x[i] <- i
  }  
  i <- i + 1
}
sum(x)

# [1] 2318
```